# Get user inputed data from HTML table

Tags: php, html-table

This is for a internal order taking web page. [It would look something like this.](http://www.invoice-templates.com/invoice1b.gif) I'm assuming I would want a HTML table for the product (from a drop down box) and quantity. My problem is how to get the data from the table once they press save. They could have entered one product or 40 products so it would need to be somewhat dynamic and not just 40 input boxes and receive them from $_POST (or maybe this is what I need to do). I guess I'm asking how to approach this. Is this something I can do with PHP or do I need to use js?

Thanks. If I'm not clear (distinct possibility) just let me know and I'll take another shot at trying to explain what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with php, have an add row button, that submits the form, don't save it, just redisplay with the post data and add another row with more inputs. But a JS version would probably give the user a better experience

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could pass it with `$_POST`.

Yes, it's possible with PHP. You'll probably also need some type of database to handle this as well

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form that collects the data in a array for example:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="item[]" /></td>
    <td>
    <select name="qty[]">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

use arrays as input field names..
like quantity[0], quantity[1]...quantity[10] etc...
then use foreach to process incoming $_POST array...

here is how you'll implement lots of rows and cols.

```
<form method="post">
<table>
<?
$rows=10;
$cols=3;
$colsArr = array();
$colsArr[0] = "qty";
$colsArr[1] = "desc";
$colsArr[2] = "unitprice";
for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=0;$j<$cols;$j++)
    {
        $name = $colsArr[$j];
        echo "<td><input type=text name=".$name."[" . $i ."]></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

take a look at this code's output's source.
when you post such a form you'll get:
(i'm posting 3 items with quantity, 1,3,5 with description desc1,desc2,desc3 and prices 1.00$,2.00$,5.00$)

```
Array ( [qty] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => ) [desc] => Array ( [0] => desc1 [1] => desc2 [2] => desc3 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => ) [unitprice] => Array ( [0] => 1.00$ [1] => 2.00$ [2] => 5.00$ [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => ) )
```